# Alternative for a WITH inside FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I`m trying to make a query in ssms that shows all errors and the amount of them.
The error message is in XML but in a nvarchar field, thats why I have to do a "with".

```
;with CastToXML as (
    select CAST(tableName.XMLField as xml) as x

        from tableName
        group by tableName.XMLField 
)
select distinct h.ep.value('(./logMessage)[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as log1
    from CastToXML
   cross apply x.nodes('xmlfield') as h(ep)
```

This doesn't allow me to do a group by log1.

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need to do a group? You're already using `distinct` which is effectively "group by all columns in the `SELECT`", and `log1` is the only column in the select.

Comment: The fact that you are using `CAST(tableName.XMLField as xml) as x` implies to ne that the column `XMLField` is not actually the `xml` datatype; ideally you should be storing your XML in an `xml` data type; especially if you're going to need to use commands like `modify`. If you aren't, however, I personally prefer using `VALUES` over a CTE. `SELECT * FROM YourTable CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(xml, NotXMLColumn))) V(X);`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm trying to count the amount per message type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a `COUNT(*)` to your final results, just move your current query into another CTE and query and group by its results (after removing the `DISTINCT`, obviously):

```
;with CastToXML as (
    select CAST(tableName.XMLField as xml) as x

        from tableName
        group by tableName.XMLField 
), Errors as (
    select h.ep.value('(./logMessage)[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as log1
        from CastToXML
            cross apply
               x.nodes('xmlfield') as h(ep)
)
select log1,COUNT(*)
from Errors
group by log1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get this correctly, you want to count the messages within your XML.

Besides the fact, that you really should store your XML in a natively typed column (the repeated cast to XML is very expensive!), you can use simple `XQuery` to achieve the same:

```
DECLARE @SomeXML XML=
N'<xmlfield>
  <logMessage>Message 1</logMessage>
  <logMessage>Message 2</logMessage>
  <logMessage>Message 3</logMessage>
  <logMessage>Message 1</logMessage>
</xmlfield>';

SELECT @SomeXML.value('count(/xmlfield/logMessage)','int') AS CountOfLogMessages
      ,@SomeXML.value('count(distinct-values(/xmlfield/logMessage))','int') AS DistinctCountOfLogMessages
```

**Hint** You can use this in your query in the same place as you've got the other `.value()` call.

Comment: I have to store it in a nvarchar field because all clients send their errors in diffrent ways. Some in xml, some in json...

Comment: @LucienRyter In this case I'd use some business logic to detect the type and store the data in an appropriate column.